# Tableau - Resource Governing with Multi-tenancy

Tags: tableau-api, multi-tenant

My proposed implementation for Tableau server is a 2 server setup with multiple sites which will all me to segregate dashboards to different groups of users.  Tableau provides all of this ability out of the box which is good.  My question is really about in production, how do I ensure that a request for a dashboard does not consume 100% of the server resources and therefore other dashboard requests will be queued.

It is always good to have an example :-)

Imagine I have 3 'sites' defined in my Tableau server, let's give these names:

Sales
Marketing
Purchasing

Tableau server has users created to permit access to dashboards within each site.  Within the Sales site is a dashboard that must run a complex query (I know I would refactor and use the facilities of Tableau to speed this up but this is purely for discussion) which takes a siginificant amount of time and aggregation within Tableau.  During this period, how can I ensure that:

Other users within Sales can still access their dashboards?
Marketing and Purchasing are not impacted by the reduced resources on the Server.

Does Tableau provide any way of governing the amount of resources on the box that is assigned to each site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the number of users that can be added to a site and can define a storage quota for a site, but I don't think there is a way to reserve CPU or network bandwidth for one site at the expense of others. All the users on the server contend for the same resources, regardless of which site defines the view.

If this is a critical factor in practice, you could stand up a second server to hold the high priority visualizations, thus reserving resources for them alone -- at the cost of a second license.